# Lists of Suggested Magazines to Submit To

Tags: poetry, publishing, magazines

I recently began writing poetry again.  I would like to look into submitting my poems to a magazine.

Where can I find a list of literary magazines through which I could sort to find a possible fit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writer's Market publishes a few different books, including one for poets, which include listings of publishers, agents, magazines, contests, anthologies, etc.

You can find them in most major bookstores. They come out once a year, but there are also listings available on their paid-subscription website: http://www.writersmarket.com/ . It's worthwhile noting that when you buy the book, you get a paid subscription for a year.

Generally speaking it focuses on the American/Canadian markets, and I'm not sure if there's something similar for the UK/Australia/New Zealand/Other English Markets.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [Poets & Writers](http://www.pw.org/). It is a bi-monthly magazine.

And as it says on their home page:

"If you’re looking for writing competitions, or literary magazines and small presses that welcome both new and established writers, begin here."

Answer (score 1):

If your work falls into the "genre" category, then the following sites might be useful:

- [Duotrope](http://www.duotrope.com/): has lots of genre entries, but also general/literary markets
- [Ralan's](http://www.ralan.com/): predominantly SF/F/H markets, but is a great site (not the greatest looking site, but good content)

Comment: +1 for Duotrope.  It's such a useful site, and amazingly still free to use.