# How can I find good venues for publishing my work?

Tags: fiction, poetry, career

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to publish poems](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/where-to-publish-poems)

I used to write poems and stories. They were published in local newspapers many times, but I did not get any benefit besides this limited publication.

I want to know how I should go about looking for larger, more widely-read venues that will be appropriate for my work. I would like to hear about specific recommended publications, but mostly about the process I should go through in order to find such publications myself. I am most looking for a venue that will let me show my talent so that people know about my creativity; eventually I would like to make writing my profession.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sameer, welcome to the site! Your question as asked was very broad, asking about how to get from here to a writing career... I've edited it to focus mostly on the first task you were interested in - finding a worthwhile platform for your work. I hope I've understood your intentions correctly; you can edit the question again if you don't like my changes or want to change anything.

Comment: @Standback - I like your edit, it makes the question a little better. I suggest that answers try to be more comprehensive and summarize the options available; I think that shorter answers will likely be converted into comments.

Comment: @Standback, great, now it's a dupe: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/where-to-publish-poems, http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/which-traditional-presses-publish-poetry, http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/19/lists-of-suggested-magazines-to-submit-to

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Quite right. Thanks for digging those up. :) Sameer - If you find that the questions John linked don't cover what you're asking, please feel free to create a new question (or edit this one) and tell us what kind of info you're still missing.

Comment: @Standback:and then john like people will close again